# Flutter build iOS stuck on Building [bundle id] for device (iOS-release)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, build

This is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

My flutter version is `Flutter 1.7.8`. I have an app that works fine on the emulator, and I've tried `flutter build ios` and `flutter build ios --release` but both give the same response of:

```
myuser@mylaptop:~/Documents/development/proj_name$ flutter build ios
Building [my bundle id] for device (ios-release)...
```

and just hangs there. I've run `flutter upgrade` and rebooted my computer multiple times. What should I do to fix this?

UPDATE: My Xcode stopped opening the project as well! It just loads on forever. I'm reinstalling Xcode right now... hoping it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix worked for me: Move the development directory outside of iCloud. Not sure why this worked, but it did.